# Comparing numbers in an array, outputting highest number

Tags: ruby

I need to write a function that takes three phone numbers in an array, adds the digits of each number seperately, and outputs the phone number with be biggest value on the screen.

Numbers are in this form [821-839-1182, 128-389-........]

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
arr = ['821-839-1182', '128-389-4732', '621-411-7324']

arr.max_by { |s| s.each_char.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+) }
  #=> "128-389-4732"
```

We have:

```
a = arr.map { |s| s.each_char.map(&:to_i) }
  #=> [[8, 2, 1, 0, 8, 3, 9, 0, 1, 1, 8, 2],
  #    [1, 2, 8, 0, 3, 8, 9, 0, 4, 7, 3, 2],
  #    [6, 2, 1, 0, 4, 1, 1, 0, 7, 3, 2, 4]] 

b = a.map { |e| e.reduce(:+) }
  #=> [43, 47, 31]
```

As the largest sum is at index 1, `max_by` will return the string at that index of arr. Note that `'-'.to_i #=> 0`.

Comment: Heck yeah, thanks. and just threw in a puts arr.max at the end to round it off, thank you.

Comment: Excellent answer although I would suggest  `arr.max_by { |s| s.split('-').map(&:to_i).reduce(:+) } `. While the concept is very similar it requires less loops and dependent on the size of `arr` this can save significant time.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the '-'s in the phone numbers and do a [radix sort](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/RadixSort.html) to get the highest value.